# I want to mock static RestTemplate object in postInvoiceByRestService method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermockito

Unable to mock Rest Template static object in my postInvoiceByRestService method I have tried lots of ways including Power Mockito Mockito spy but did not work for me What strategy need to use mock static Rest Template object?

Java Class

```
public class PeopleSoftInvoiceRestPublisher {
    private static final String UPDATED_BY = "DFIINVP";

    private static final String TAX_ACCOUNT = "241900";
    private static URL serverURL;
    private static RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws DfiException, SQLException {
        getWLConnection();
        PeopleSoftInvoiceRestPublisher peopleSoftInvoiceRestPublisher = new PeopleSoftInvoiceRestPublisher();
        peopleSoftInvoiceRestPublisher.publishInvoices();
    }

    

    public void postInvoiceByRestService(PeopleSoftRecordBuilder builder) {
        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();

        header.add("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(
                (DfiResources.getResource("PS_USER") + ":" + DfiResources.getResource("PS_PASSWORD")).getBytes()));
        PostInvoiceRequestDTO postInvoiceRequestDTO = getPostInvoiceRequestDTO(builder);
        HttpEntity<PostInvoiceRequestDTO> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<PostInvoiceRequestDTO>(postInvoiceRequestDTO,
                header);
        try {
            ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
            DfiLog.info("Request JSON Payload ::  " + ow.writeValueAsString(postInvoiceRequestDTO));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }

        DfiLog.info("Request Payload ::  " + postInvoiceRequestDTO.toString());

        String urlTemplate = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(DfiResources.getResource("PS_POST_URL")).toUriString();
        // .queryParam("From_date", getYesterdayDate()).queryParam("To_date",
        // modifiedDate).toUriString();
        DfiLog.info("Request Rest endpoint :: " + urlTemplate);
        
         ResponseEntity<String> invoiceResponseEntity =  restTemplate.exchange(urlTemplate, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity,String.class); 
         DfiLog.info("Response Entity :: " + invoiceResponseEntity.toString());
         
    }
}
```

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ DfiResources.class, DfiLog.class, UriComponentsBuilder.class })
//@PrepareEverythingForTest
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.swing.*")
public class PeopleSoftInvoiceRestPublisherTest {

    

    @InjectMocks
    private PeopleSoftInvoiceRestPublisher peopleSoftInvoiceRestPublisher;
      
    /*@Mock 
    RestTemplate restTemplate;
    */ 
       
     
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        
    }

    
    @Test
    public void testCase() throws Exception {

        PeopleSoftRecordBuilder peopleSoftRecordBuilder = new PeopleSoftRecordBuilder();
        
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DfiResources.class);
        when(DfiResources.getResource("PS_USER")).thenReturn("USER");
        when(DfiResources.getResource("PS_PASSWORD")).thenReturn("PASSWORD");
        when(DfiResources.getResource(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("PASSWORD");
        when(DfiResources.getResource("PS_POST_URL")).thenReturn("https://example.com/hotels/42?filter={value}");
        
        PowerMockito.mock(DfiLog.class);

        peopleSoftRecordBuilder.invoiceAmt(new BigDecimal(10.0));
        peopleSoftRecordBuilder.invoiceNum("1234");
        peopleSoftRecordBuilder.supplierNumber("567");
        peopleSoftRecordBuilder.setQtyDelivered(new BigDecimal(210.0));
        
        PowerMockito.mock(UriComponentsBuilder.class);
        //PowerMockito.mockStatic(RestTemplate.class);
        //RestTemplate t1=new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> str=new ResponseEntity<String>("dsffdsd",HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        RestTemplate restTemplate= Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);
        when(restTemplate.exchange(Matchers.any(String.class),Matchers.any(HttpMethod.class),Matchers.<HttpEntity<?>> any() ,Matchers.<Class<?>>any())
        ).thenReturn(null);
        //doNothing().when(restTemplate).exchange(Matchers.any(String.class),Matchers.any(HttpMethod.class),Matchers.<HttpEntity<?>> any() ,Matchers.<Class<?>>any());
        
      peopleSoftInvoiceRestPublisher.postInvoiceByRestService(peopleSoftRecordBuilder);

        

    }
}
```

Unable to mock RestTemplate static object in my postInvoiceByRestService method ?

I tried multiple ways using PowerMockito & Mockito , spy but did not get output. PLs let me know what is wrong I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Power Mock gives you access to mock static methods, constructors etc. and this means that your code is not following best programming principles.

Power Mock should be used in legacy applications where you cannot change the code which has been given to you. Often such code does not have unit/integration tests and even small change can result in bugs in application. So be careful.

I think you gave not proper values when you are mocking restTemplate.exchange().

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = PowerMockito.mockStatic(RestTemplate.class);
        when(restTemplate.exchange(anyString(), any(HttpMethod.class), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(String.class)))
                .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>("response", HttpStatus.OK));

        PeopleSoftRecordBuilder builder = new PeopleSoftRecordBuilder();
        // set builder fields
        peopleSoftInvoiceRestPublisher.postInvoiceByRestService(builder);

        // assert expected behavior
        verify(restTemplate, times(1)).exchange(anyString(), any(HttpMethod.class), any(HttpEntity.class),
                eq(String.class));
    }
```